# Missing either data or entire lines on serial port read

Tags: perl, winapi

I am trying to read streaming serial data at 115200b and cant seem to pick it all up.

using the input method ($data = $Port -> input), I get the first 14 or 15 characters of every line.  I need the whole line.

using the read method ($data= $Port -> read(4096)) and by adjusting the read_interval I can either get partials of every line using 
$Port->read_interval(1);

or fully every third line using 
$Port->read_interval(2);
I need all of every line.

here is the code

```
my $App_Main_Port = Win32::SerialPort->start ($Test_cfgfile);  
$App_Main_Port->read_interval(1);  
$App_Main_Port->read_char_time(1);   
for ($i=0;;) {   
    # $data = $App_Main_Port -> input;   
    $data= $App_Main_Port -> read(4096);   
    print "$data\n";  
}
```

by adjusting the read interval I get the results mentioned above.  I started with the default values of 100 in the interval and char_time parameters, but only get every third line.

Tx for any insight!
Chris

Comment: Please show code the demonstrates the problem. At least mention what module you're using!

Answer (score 0):

Serial port reads often just return what's buffered in the serial port at that moment.  A 16550 UART only buffers 16 bytes total, and that's what most PCs emulate.

From the Win32::SerialPort page, it appears you need to call `->read()` in a list context, so you can find out how many bytes actually got read.  If you really do want to block until you've received all 4K characters, try a loop like this:

```
# read in 4K bytes
my ($data, $temp, $count_in, $total_in);
$total_in = 0;
while ($total_in < 4096) {
    ( $count_in, $temp ) = $App_Main_Port->read( 4096 - $total_in );
    $data .= $temp;
    $total_in += $count_in;
}
```

That said, your real problem sounds like it could be a flow control issue.  Even with such a loop, you might still get dropped characters if you don't have proper flow control.  You might experiment with `handshake("dtr")` or `handshake("rts")`.